# "Trusted Sites" settings in Google Chrome

Tags: security, google-chrome, internet-explorer

Is there equivalent of Internet Explorer **Trusted Sites** settings in Google Chrome?

Here is the issue:

When I download an excel file from a website using Chrome the file is marked as unsafe as seen on the security section in the properties window:

[image]

As the consequence the file is open in "Protected View" by Excel 2010.

When using Internet Explorer once the site is added to trusted sites that flag is not set and the files open normally. Can I achieve that behaviour in Chrome?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You cant do it Google Chrome**

> This is has been a known issue with
>   Google chrome, if i am right you
>   cannot put anything as  Trusted Sites
>   in Google Chrome. But you can sure put
>   SSL certificate to Trusted

This site might be able to give u some information
 http://www.google.me/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=2b7f28ce2a06b2d0&hl=en

Comment: An answer was added to the linked thread in 2011:  "Basically Chrome is using the Windows Internet Options. Therefore you can go straight away to Control Panel in Windows - > Internet Option 

Internet Options -> Privacy -> Sites - > Allow  or Deny the sites."  So it seems the the chrome is now using Windows settings directly.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it!**

(Click horizontal bars in upper right of Chrome to open settings menu) --> Settings --> Show Advanced Settings… --> Network --> Change Proxy Settings --> Security Tab.

There you will see the interface for modifying trusted sites (the same interface that you see in IE).

These settings are at the machine level, not the browser level.  Setting them in one browser automatically applies the settings to other browsers.

After making changes, be sure to close all chrome tabs/browsers and re-open for changes to take effect.

Comment: These settings don't seem to be used by firefox.  Associated settings can be found and updated for firefox by typing about:config in the address bar.

Comment: This appears to only work under Windows.

Comment: No longer works in windows 10 at least