# How do I bypass this since I know the site is good

Tags: firefox, certificate, bypass

This Connection is Untrusted

You have asked Firefox to connect securely to xhopsportal.sys.comcast.net, but we can't confirm that your connection is secure.

Normally, when you try to connect securely, sites will present trusted identification to prove that you are going to the right place. However, this site's identity can't be verified.
What Should I Do?

If you usually connect to this site without problems, this error could mean that someone is trying to impersonate the site, and you shouldn't continue.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](https://superuser.com/a/622684/147220) question:

> (Click horizontal bars in upper right of Chrome to open settings menu)
>   --> Settings --> Show Advanced Settings… --> Network --> Change Proxy Settings --> Security Tab.
>
> There you will see the interface for modifying trusted sites (the same
>   interface that you see in IE).
>
> These settings are at the machine level, not the browser level. 
>   Setting them in one browser automatically applies the settings to
>   other browsers.
>
> After making changes, be sure to close all chrome tabs/browsers and
>   re-open for changes to take effect.

Just add the URL to the trusted sites.